# add an empty line inside text file

Tags: c#, .net, string, text

So let me give you an example of how my file could look:

```
Hello
my
name
is
```

Now, for example, I want to go through the different lines of this file with System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(); and then check with a loop whether the current line has the word "my" in it (so the second line in this case).

As my next step, I want to add a new line right after "my", so it looks like this:

```
Hello
my

name
is
```

I approached this with 2 methods now. I was hoping File.Append(); would offer a method where I could append anything *after* it has found the string I am looking for, but obviously it only offers methods to append strings to the end of files.

My second approach was to read in all the lines with string[] test=System.IO.File.ReadAllLines();
and then iterate through all the lines, checking each line with

```
for (int i = 0; i < (test.Length - 1); i++)
{
    if(test[i].Contains("my"))
    {
        test[i] = test[i] + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

and then write all this back in the file with System.IO.File.WriteAllLines();

The problem I am facing here is the fact that this command does not really add a real new line to the file, as I've checked test.Length before and after, and both time I got 4 as a result.

Comment: And you are writing the result back? Can you show us more code?

Comment: Try using StringBuilder instead: read the lines one by one (instread of ReadAllLines(); you're using) and use Append() or AppendLine().

Comment: instead of `Environment.NewLine` use `\r\n` to add after the string

Comment: @VDesign what difference would that make? If running in Windows (or more appropriately, non Unix systems), `Environment.NewLine` is the literal string "\r\n". See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to add the lines to a List which would give you the Insert() method:
*Only use this for relatively small files.

Something like:

```
        string path = @"c:\some\path\file.txt";
        List<String> lines = new List<string>(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path));
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
        {
            if (lines[i].Contains("my"))
            {
                if (i < lines.Count -1)
                {
                    lines.Insert(i + 1, "");
                }
                else
                {
                    lines.Add("");
                }
            }
        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, lines.ToArray());
```

Comment: This was the perfect answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you use `StringBuilder`. It's best to use it when you're adding many strings, since strings are immutable and thus each string is created again when you do `+=`, or simply assigning a new one to an array slot.

This code will do what you're looking for, and it treats the no new line edge case:

```
            var filePath = //your file path
            var test = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < (test.Length - 1); i++)
            {
                sb.Append(test[i]);
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                if (test[i].Contains("my"))
                {
                    // This adds that extra new line
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
            sb.Append(test[test.Length-1]);

            File.WriteAllText(filePath,  sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[TestMethod]
    public void InsertLines()
    {
        var test = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\SUService.log");
        var list = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < (test.Length - 1); i++)
        {
            list.Add(test[i]);
            if (test[i].Contains("my"))
            {
                list.Add(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\SUService.log", list);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not for the above question: But in general if you want to add a new line after a line you just have to add a new line character -> so if you want to add an empty line after a line **Just add 2 newline characters**

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath,"\n\n");
```

Here the the writer will jump 2 times and add the upcoming contents in the send line